# Code Igniter caching - time to remain cached

Tags: class, codeigniter, caching

I have read this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html. And there is nothing about the time to data to remain cached.

I want to cache the following query:

```
private $table_name = 'mytable';
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
return $query->result();
```

And I want to store it with the same id as the `$query->id` is, with the 5 minutes cache remain.

Is that possible , using the CI's caching class?

Answer (score 1):

With CodeIgniter's caching system it is up to you to clear the cache with whatever algorithm makes the most sense for your site.  The queries are cached into files which you will need to delete in order to clear.

For what it's worth I would highly recommend using APC as your cache.  It allows you to cache php objects in memory, which is far more efficient.  See:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php